yarn ts-node-dev requires defining dependency to src folder
Can you help me understand this behavior and share how would you solve this "properly"?
I'm running Node.JS (v20.12.2), Yarn (4.1.1), tsc (5.4.5) and have following goals:

Run the app locally with ts-node & ts-node-dev.
Export the app with tsc to run in elsewhere.

I can run (2) yarn build (basically yarn tsc), then node dist/server.js works.
I fail at (1) yarn dev / start (yarn ts-node ./src/index.ts) both fail with the error below. If I do what it says and add ./src folder as dependency in package.json it works, but that looks very strange to me... I don't get why tsc is able to work with the src folder and ts-node is not. Is that really how this is supposed to work or I miss something obvious? Thanks!
File structure:
- project home
  - package.json
  - .pnp.cjs
  - tsconfig.json
  - src 
    - server.ts
  - dist
    - server.js

Error:
$ yarn ts-node-dev --exit-child src/server.ts 
<project-root>/.pnp.cjs:7812
  return Object.defineProperties(new Error(message), {
                                 ^

Error: Your application tried to access src, but it isn't declared in your dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: src (via "src/server.ts")
Required by: <project-root>/

    at makeError (<project-root>/.pnp.cjs:7812:34)
    at resolveToUnqualified (<project-root>/.pnp.cjs:9450:21)
    at resolveRequest (<project-root>/.pnp.cjs:9587:31)
    at <project-root>/api/.pnp.cjs:9650:26
    at resolveRequest (<project-root>/.yarn/__virtual__/ts-node-dev-virtual-1a2df4f79d/6/.yarn/berry/cache/ts-node-dev-npm-2.0.0-a9d487396c-10c0.zip/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/resolveMain.js:11:16)
    at exports.resolveMain <project-root>/.yarn/__virtual__/ts-node-dev-virtual-1a2df4f79d/6/.yarn/berry/cache/ts-node-dev-npm-2.0.0-a9d487396c-10c0.zip/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/resolveMain.js:30:20)
    at exports.runDev (<project-root>/.yarn/__virtual__/ts-node-dev-virtual-1a2df4f79d/6/.yarn/berry/cache/ts-node-dev-npm-2.0.0-a9d487396c-10c0.zip/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/index.js:53:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<project-root>/.yarn/__virtual__/ts-node-dev-virtual-1a2df4f79d/6/.yarn/berry/cache/ts-node-dev-npm-2.0.0-a9d487396c-10c0.zip/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/bin.js:136:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)

package.json:
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.1.1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "test-app",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --exit-child ./src/index.ts",
    "start": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node-lts": "^20.1.3",
    "@types/express": "^4",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "graphql-http": "^1.22.1"
  }
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node-lts/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Emit */
    "outDir": "dist",
  }
}



https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/289

As suggested by @Andy above (thanks!), Following https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/289#issuecomment-916938133 it works by using relative paths...
Fails:
$ yarn ts-node-dev --exit-child src/server.ts
Works:
$ yarn ts-node-dev --exit-child ./src/server.ts

just so you know - you can mark your own answer as correct.

yes, Stackoverflow says I can do that in 2 days ;-)
